# Custom LWC Flow Screen Component - use Picklist/Record Choice Set as input

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, flowscreen

Is there a way to accept a Picklist Choice Set or Record Choice Set in a custom LWC Flow Screen Component?

e.g.

I'm creating a Flow Screen Component and I want to define an input as being a Picklist Choice Set or Record Choice Set.

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">​
            <property name="choice" label="Choice" type=" ** Choice ** " role="inputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I want to set the property `Type` to a choice set.

According to the [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags), the only values for Type are:

- Boolean
- Integer
- String
- apex://namespace.Classname
- Date
- DateTime
- @salesforce/schema/Objectname

There is a custom `propertyType` that we can define, but I don't see how I can use that for this.

The goal here is to create a custom LWC flow screen component that make it easy for the user to define the values provided to it.

Comment: As per this documentation https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_flow_data_types you should be able to pass the flow Picklist data type in lwc as String property.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I set it as string, the js picklist variable setter is never called.